# Extra space present between the parent div and child div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am placing a `div` inside another `div`. Please see the code below [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s5nx6w3f/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="set1"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0;
}

.set1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 5px solid;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here I am expecting the height of parent div = the height of child. But that's not the case as seen in fig below. I have applied `box-sizing : border-box` hence the border for the parent should be included in it's height but is not the case. Can you please explain? Also how can I make the child to fully occupy the parent in such case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because of border(1px each side), use maybe outline instead.

set1

[image: set1]

wrapper
[image: wrapper]

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. Still wondering why `box-sizing: border-box` isn't working on the parent `div`.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you are using a border on wrapper which adds these 2px to height.

If you want that the wrapper has the same height as the parent, you can use a margin on set1 div.

Like this:

```
.set1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 5px solid;
  margin: -1px 0;
}
```

So the margin should always have the height of the wrapper border.
Here your working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzs9u7m2/2/

Comment: Cool solution. But when checked the height of elements, I can see the parent is of `102px` while the child is of `100px` as I mentioned in the figure above. Any idea why it's happening even after applying `border-box` to the elements. Technically parent height should also be equal to `100px`.

Comment: Hmm, i created 2 screenshots and both div's have 100px height. So if you open this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gzs9u7m2/3/ ... you see parent height 102px?